Plot Hypothetical Future Bar using PineScript
I want to plot a candlestick chart where candlesticks at time t are plotted using actual data and for future dates I want to continue the chart and plot using hypothetical data. How can it be done?
plotcandle(100 , 100, 100, 100, title = 'Title', color = open < close ? color.green : color.red, wickcolor = color.black)
In the above code I can define hypothetical data but I am unable to offset it by 1 day.
Update:
So I worked out another method with allows to apply hypothetical data but does not overwrites the existing candles after offset date.
//@version=5
indicator("Candlestick with Hypothetical Data", overlay=true)

// Define the cutoff date for switching from actual to hypothetical data
cutoff_date = timestamp("2024-09-12 00:00") // Replace with your desired cutoff date

// Get the current bar's time
current_time = time

// Actual Data (using built-in OHLC values until the cutoff date)
actualOpen = current_time <= cutoff_date ? open : na
actualHigh = current_time <= cutoff_date ? high : na
actualLow = current_time <= cutoff_date ? low : na
actualClose = current_time <= cutoff_date ? close : na

// Hypothetical Data (only appears after the cutoff date)
last_actual_close = ta.valuewhen(current_time <= cutoff_date, close, 0) // Close value of the last actual data bar
hypOpen = current_time > cutoff_date ? 150 : na
hypHigh = current_time > cutoff_date ? 150 : na
hypLow = current_time > cutoff_date ? 150 : na
hypClose = current_time > cutoff_date ? 150 : na

// Plot both actual and hypothetical candlesticks
// Plot Actual Candlesticks
plotcandle(open = actualOpen, high = actualHigh, low = actualLow, close = actualClose, title = "Actual Data", color = actualOpen < actualClose ? color.green : color.red, wickcolor = color.black)

// Plot Hypothetical Candlesticks
plotcandle(open = hypOpen, high = hypHigh, low = hypLow, close = hypClose, title = "Hypothetical Data", color = hypOpen < hypClose ? color.blue : color.orange, wickcolor = color.gray)


plotcandle() does not have an offset argument so you cannot do that with it.
As a workaround, you can use box and line. It won't look the same because your custom candle will be 3-candle wide.
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true, max_boxes_count=500, max_lines_count=500)

f_draw_candle(p_o, p_h, p_l, p_c, p_offset) =>
    is_green = (p_c >= p_o)
    candle_left = bar_index + p_offset
    candle_right = bar_index + p_offset + 2     // Candle body will be 3 candles long
    candle_wick = int(math.avg(candle_left, candle_right))
    candle_top = math.max(p_o, p_c)
    candle_bot = math.min(p_o, p_c)
    candle_color = is_green ? #089981 : #f23645

    box.new(candle_left, candle_top, candle_right, candle_bot, candle_color, bgcolor=candle_color)
    line.new(candle_wick, candle_top, candle_wick, p_h, color=candle_color)
    line.new(candle_wick, candle_bot, candle_wick, p_l, color=candle_color)

if (barstate.islast)
    f_draw_candle(open, high, low, close, 20)



So if I set p_offset as 1, the candle would be 3-candle wide. Why is that so can you explain a bit? thanks

Because of the wick. I assume you want to have the wick right in the middle. Therefore, bar #1 is the left edge, bar #2 is the wick and bar #3 is the right edge.

So let's say if you have a candle at 16th (using actual data) then next candle should be on 17th using hypothetical data.
